# How to White Part of JPG in PictureBox transparent

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

I have a JPG image and have it in a picture box in a form, however, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it so that the white part of the picture disappears, and only the colored parts appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MakeTransparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds.aspx) method on Bitmap class. So it will be something like

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap("img.jpg")
b.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
pictureBox.Image = b;
```

But I recommend you to use PNG instead of JPG for this reason: a) better quality (for images like this) c) smaller size for images like this b) native support of transparent backgrounds.

Take a look on what is the difference between them http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=PNG+vs+JPG

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile( @"C:\your_k.bmp" ); //Load a bitmap from file
    bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White) //Do the work!
    //if you have a varient color combination you can use RGB Combination as follows
    //bmp.MakeTransparent( Color.FromArgb( 255, 255 255 ) ); //  (255 255, 255) is  white!
    this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    this.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent; //makes humbly only your object!
```